# nginx: Upstream SSL, how is it encrypting on the backend?

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, https

I've been researching this question, and cannot find a definitive answer.  I am really trying to get a grasp on this before deploying to production, and most nginx resources I've found aren't very clear at explaining what's happening behind nginx when serving traffic to the proxies.

Basically, I am trying to encrypt requests both to the client from nginx, and from nginx to the proxied servers behind it. After reading, and following examples, I've come up with a config that seems to be working. At least working in that the client is receiving requests over SSL.

My question is whether my original concern of encrypting traffic both ways is actually accomplished with the following config or if the connections from nginx to the proxied servers are still over http rather than https:

```
upstream app1 {
        server app1:3000;
}

upstream app2 {
        server app2:5000;
}

server {
       listen         80 default_server;
       listen    [::]:80 default_server;
       server_name    localhost;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen            443 ssl http2;
        listen            [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name       localhost;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/localhost-cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/localhost-privkey.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://app1;
        }

        location /api {
          proxy_pass http://app2;
        }
}
```

If the connections from nginx to the proxied servers are still in plaintext, how would I go about encrypting that data as well from nginx rather than from the app servers themselves?

Comment: In essence:ensure that your application servers are available over https and then  change the http in `proxy_pass http://app1;` to HTTPS  `proxy_pass https://app1;`

Comment: The second configuration you posted still uses an unencrypted HTTP connection to the backends app1 + app2! The only thing that changed is an additional proxying step from the host's port 443 to the host's port 3000 & 5000 on the lo interface. To encrypt the connection from host to backends, simply proxy_pass to httpS://appXYZ - and make sure the backends do indeed support HTTPS! Also, don't be afraid to post an answer to your own question. This way people can comment and vote on just your answer!

Comment: When I do that, I receive the error that I posted down below in response to Quantim. I can configure the backends to issue their own SSL cert, but I was hoping that nginx could establish the HTTPS requests. Is this possible? Also, when you say to "make sure the backends do indeed support HTTPS", are you saying to configure them to issue their own certs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your config use plain HTTP to contact backend servers, for securing this path you need to use https on this part too. There is perfect article how to achieve this in [official doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/)

Comment: I actually referenced that exact document when trying to figure this out. The problem is when I add the certs to the upstream proxies, I get the following error when making a request to either app which leads down a million different rabbit holes on Google that lead me no where:

`SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://172.19.0.3:3000/favicon.ico", host: "localhost", referrer: "https://localhost/"`

Comment: and upstream server has SSL on port `3000` ? this error looks like you try to HTTPS connection on port where is only HTTP